# SQL Query- Case & Substr

Tags: sql, case, substr

I have a column which i got using a substr function and this column has alphabets. How do i change the alphabets to words?

```
select orderid,
       substr(ordernumber,10,1) as Process
from Table1,
where XXXXXX
```

If there is "M" in the column Process, then it should replace it with "Maintenance" and if it is "O", then it should be "Operations".

```
Process ---> Process
M            maintenance
O            Operations
```

Can someone help me how i should change the substr statement to update the column?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT orderid,
       CASE SUBSTR(ordernumber, 10, 1) WHEN 'M' THEN 'maintenance'
                                       WHEN 'O' THEN 'Operations'
       END AS Process
FROM   table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use update statement with `case` expression :

```
update table 
     set Process = (case substr(ordernumber, 10, 1) 
                         when 'M' then 'maintenance'
                         when 'O' then 'Operations'
                    end)
where substr(ordernumber, 10, 1) in ('M', 'O');
```